# pass a pointer from one activity to another

Tags: android, pointers, android-activity

I have two activities. I use the first one for simulate a "log in" for the user, and in the next activity i pass the "usuarios" object where i have all the users. The problem is that when I delete one user from one activity it is not shown in the other activity. I'm not using pointers?

code from the log in activity:

```
public void ejecutarIniciarSesion (View view){

    TextView usuario = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textField_usuario);
    TextView password= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textField_pass);

    String pass = usuarios.getPass(usuario.getText().toString());

    if (password.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(pass)){

        usuarios.getUsuario(usuario.getText().toString()).Set_Conected(1);
        Intent actividad = new Intent(this, MiCuenta.class);
        actividad.putExtra("usuarios", usuarios);
        actividad.putExtra("user",usuario.getText().toString());
        usuario.setText("");
        password.setText("");
        startActivity(actividad);
    }

    else{
        usuario.setText("");
        contraseña.setText("");
    }
}
```

Here is where i get the Object:

public class MiCuenta extends Activity {

```
PruebaUsuarios usuarios;
String nombre,apellidos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mi_cuenta);

    usuarios = (PruebaUsuarios) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("usuarios");

    nombre = usuarios.userOnline();
    apellidos = usuarios.getUsuario(nombre).Get_Apellidos();

    TextView nombreText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView correoText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    nombreText.setText("Benvingut "+nombre+" "+apellidos);
    correoText.setText("Correo: "+usuarios.getUsuario(nombre).Get_Email());
}
```

And here is where i delete the object, from class MiCuenta:

public void ejecutarBorrarCuenta (View view){

```
    usuarios.borrarUsuario(nombre);
    this.finish(); 

}
```

I use vector.removeAllElements(), but in the other activity the vector still contains everything. Why this is happening?

Comment: use startActivityForResult and on callback, update the code in first activity.  http://hmkcode.com/android-startactivityforresult/

Answer (score 0):

When you passing object with intent you are not passing a pointer to it. Object (like list in your case) is serializing when you put it to intent, and than deserializing when you obtaining it. So, you should find another way to get actual data from your first activity